# Poweroff Lenovo Flex 2-15 notebook in Linux

Tags: linux, bios, shutdown, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Flex 2-15 notebook.
When I try to shut down my laptop using `poweroff/shutdown` commands or using the GUI, it shuts down completely, but after a few seconds, it turns on automatically! (be sure that I didn't press any button).

This problem does not happen in Windows, but I have this problem in Linux.

I have tried both BIOS and UEFI firmwares.

Any ideas about why this happens?

Should I update BIOS/UEFI? Or, could it be a problem with the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You can disable xHCI on the BIOS, it works for me.

Look at these links:

http://www.debianizzati.org/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50918

https://askubuntu.com/questions/488216/ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-laptop-cannot-remain-powered-off-after-shutdown-powers-off

It will fix the shutdown issue, but now my computer doesn't read the SD card. I don't know if it's a BIOS problem, maybe I have to update it.

UPDATE 1: I updated the BIOS, and now the SD card reader works fine! I only had to change another time the BIOS settings and to reinstall GRUB.

UPDATE 2: With the BIOS update, my PC has shut down only once, but the problem persist.

Now I fixed it this way:

- Enable xHCI option in the BIOS.
- Open terminal and type:

$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

- Modify the file like that:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet xhci_hcd.quirks=262144"

- make:

$ sudo update-grub

Sorry for my English, I hope it will be useful!

SOURCES:
[First site (French)](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lenovo_flex_2_14)
[Second site (English)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171)
[Third site (Italian)](http://www.debianizzati.org/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50918)

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to help with this question.  What you posted isn't a very actionable answer.  The key information is somewhere else, and will be lost entirely if the links rot.  Your update doesn't explain how to accomplish your solution.  Please make your answer more self-contained by including all of the essential information within it.  Use links just for attribution and further reading.